# Why does CMD.EXE deletes files with an extension that doesn't match

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I struggled over a batch file that deletes files that (in my eyes) don't match.

Simple sample. I have 2 files in a folder

- foo.lic
- foo.licpkg

The batch command line should delete the files with the lic extension, so there is a command

```
del %folder%\*.lic
```

But surprise, the file with the .licpkg extension is deleted too? Why?

Where is the documentation for this behavior?

BTW: My CMD.EXE Take Command (TCC) doesn't behave like this.

Comment: It matches short and long name of the file.

Comment: [WinXP dir command: 3 and 4 char extensions are the same?](https://superuser.com/q/238900/241386)

Comment: That's the answer! Thank you!

Comment: one workaround is to use a short for loop and verify the extention. `for %i in ("*.lic") do if /i "%~xi"==".lic" del "%~i"`

Answer (score 2):

For information to future readers, as the question wasn't itself looking for a solution to the problem, but a reason for it, here are some methods of deleting all files with a `.lic` extension only, in `C:\Users\xMRi\Desktop`, from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), but without disabling the 8.3 filenames. The examples should work irrespective of whether the files have system, read-only, or hidden attributes, *(subject to the appropriate permissions)*.

Using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic):

```batch-file
@"%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe" DataFile Where "Drive='C:' And Path='\\Users\\xMRi\\Desktop\\' And Extension='lic'" Delete >NUL 2>&1
```

Using a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop):

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('"(Set PATHEXT=) & "%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /F "C:\Users\xMRi\Desktop":"*.lic" 2>NUL"') Do @Del /A /F %%G
```

Using [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles):

```batch-file
@"%__APPDIR__%forfiles.exe" /P "C:\Users\xMRi\Desktop" /M "*.lic" /C "\"%__APPDIR__%cmd.exe\" /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE Del /A /F @File\""
```

Using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```batch-file
@"%__APPDIR__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Users\xMRi\Desktop\*' -Include '*.lic' -Force"
```

Please note that I have, in all instances, 'overquoted', in order that it can be used as a template for future users to replace the target path and extension without fear of spaces or other poison characters affecting the code.

Comment: The `where` command is still not safe, because it regards the `PATHEXT` variable, so the pattern `*.lic` may return `foo.lic` plus `foo.lic.exe`, for example; temporarily deleting `PATHEXT` (for instance, in the same `cmd` instance where `where` is executed) would fix that…

Comment: Thank you, @aschipfl, you are correct, any file in the case of this answer with an extension listed under `%PATHEXT%`, which is immediately preceded with `.lic` would be picked up, using that particular method, although files with an extension `.licpkg` will not be, which was the intention when posting. I agree it isn't safe for that reason, I have therefore adjusted that answer accordingly, _(although I'm unable to test it so I'd appreciate feedback as necessary)_.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I had the opportunity to successfully test your adapted code…